# PHPDoc inline {@link} (and Netbeans)

Tags: php, netbeans, phpdoc

Perhaps I'm not understanding completely, but I'm trying to get the `{@link}` inline PHPDoc tag to link to another method in the class (*the docblock in question is for a "shorthand alias" method*)

I haven't actually generated anything to documentation, but the `{@link}` is showing as plain-text in the NetBeans method descriptor. Am I doing something wrong syntactically (*if I compile the documentation will this work?*) or just that NetBeans is unable to support the inline `{@link}`?

For example:

```
class MyClass
{

    /**
     * Shorthand alias for {@link MyClass::method()}
     *
     * @param mixed $foo
     * @param mixed $bar
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __invoke($foo, $bar)
    {
        return $this->method($foo, $bar);
    }

    /**
     * Does stuff with $foo and $bar
     *
     * @param mixed $foo
     * @param mixed $bar
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function method($foo, $bar)
    {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Netbeans doesn't support all of PHP doc (yet!), it'll probably work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile the documentation, it should work then, otherwise PHPDoc will spit out an error message telling you more.

Netbeans *might* not support all PHPDoc features, you can also try `@see`.

Comment: Also see an issue for autocomplete here: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=200891

Comment: @Nux: Thanks for the cross-link, very valuable!