# phpdocumentator2, phpdoc, won't parse inline links

Tags: phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

I'm have issues trying to get inline tags to methods working, with `phpDocumentor version 2.0.0a12`. Using the sample code below, no matter what I try (eg /global/foo::bar(), foo::bar, foo::bar() etc) in the {@link parameter} the text gets printed out everytime, instead of parsed as an html anchor tag.

Is anybody else seeing this?

```
<?php
/**
 * File docblock thingy
 */

/**
 * Class docblock thingy
 */
class foo{

    /**
     * Description for bar {@link http://google.ie click for google} this is the inline link
     * @return boolean Default true
     */
    public function bar(){
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Description for baz {@link foo::bar()}
     * @return boolean Default false
     */
    public function baz(){
        return false;
    }

}
```

Maybe I'm missing a config parameter? The config using for above is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<phpdoc>
  <parser>
    <target>.</target>
    <default-package-name>Foo</default-package-name>
    <parseprivate>on</parseprivate>
  </parser>

  <transformer>
    <target>docs</target>
  </transformer>
  <files>
    <directory>.</directory>
  </files>
</phpdoc>
```

This could be considered a duplicate of [PHPDoc inline {@link} (and Netbeans)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692309/phpdoc-inline-link-and-netbeans) but I dont' think so because I'm calling phpdoc from command line (not using and IDE).
Any help seriously appreciated ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline {@link} is not yet implemented in v2 -- http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/link.html

Comment: Don't panic ;-)  It's coming soon :-)

Comment: @ashnazg is it? Your comment was from 2013... Their documentation STILL says it hasn't been implemented...